# How to persist/keep sqlite database in docker container application?

Tags: sqlite, docker

I am using gophish framework, I have dockerized the gophish using the below docker file:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
unzip \
ca-certificates \
wget && \
apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN apt-get update && \ 
apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /opt/gophish-v0.6.0-linux-64bit

# Copy everything from the current directory to the PWD(Present Working Directory) inside the container
COPY . .

RUN sed -i "s|**.**.**.***|0.0.0.0|g" config.json && \
chmod +x gophish

EXPOSE 80 80 8089 8089

ENTRYPOINT ["./gophish"]
```

the app is running fine on the Azure virtual machine and on local, the problem is the SQLite database is in docker container itself so on every docker build the database become blank.
how can I keep the SQLite database?

New to docker.
any help?

Comment: You should not keep the data files inside the container itself. Use volumes for this. Not sure how exactly this is done in Azure, but the concept is the same for all platforms: you mount an external volume into your container and tell the database to store the data files to this location so that they survive the container recreation.

Comment: Containers are, by very design, temporary, and hold no persistent data. If you need persistent data, you store it outside of the container, either over a network service, or with a volume.